# How to configure additional tags depending on metric name for actuator metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Is there anyway I can configure what tags to add to @Timed metrics? I know overriding MebMvcTagsProvider or WebMvcTagsContributor classes will return a standard set of tags common for all mvc metrics. But is there any way I can exclude or include some tags with dynamic values for some metrics? Like in this case:

```
WebMvcTagsProvider object -> provides a set of tags whose values like status etc. are set here -> tag1, val1; tag2, val2
```

and then we have a rest api like this:

```
@Timed("metric.1")
public String api1() {}
```

and another api like this:

```
@Timed("metric.2")
public String api2() {}
```

so with this, after invoking both the apis, we'll get these metrics, both having same set of tags

> metric-1(tag1="val1", tag2="val2", status=201)
> metric-2(tag1="val1", tag2="val2", status=200)

but can we return different set of tags for both of these metrics, like this:

> metric-1(tag1="val1", status=201)
> metric-2(tag2="val2", status=200)

I found a WebMvcMetricsFilter class which's what all the metrics are going through to generate timers, is there some way I can make use of this to configure what tags are returned based on metric name?

Can someone please help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

One option (since it is spring and there could be many ways of doing this) is to declare a micrometer `MeterFilter` and update the tags based on names.

```java
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if(id.getName().equals("metric-1")) {
                return id.withTags(Tags.of("foo", "bar"));
            }
            // more conditions here
            return id;
        }
    };
}
```

Check this documentation (section 6.2) from micrometer on how to transform metrics. You can add, update or remove tags this way.

Comment: problem with this is that tags should be static, I can't assign values to some fields like say status of response etc. if I filter out tags this way

Comment: What does it mean by static?

Comment: as in not dynamic. don't we need to give the values of the tags here as constants?

Comment: You could use a naming convention for your tags and use a `startsWith` or `contains` as well. The name from `Meter.Id` is a `String` object.

Comment: here, we're returning tag like this, right?
id.withTags(Tags.of("foo", "bar"));
where "bar" is a set value which can't be set based on some other data?

Comment: @user97, were you able to come up with a solution to your problem? I am looking for something similar and would appreciate if I can get some help on this.